# More problems installing Android SDK and Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, ide

My first issue is: I cannot seem to find an executable for the `Android SDK`! I have downloaded and installed via the `Android SDK Manager` the necessarie files, at least I hope I have. To start the ball rolling I download: `API 15`, `Android  SDK` tools and platform tools plus `Android 3.2`. Am I missing something? The problem is I cannot find any executable file to run my `Android SDK! Where is it?

I then went on to download `Eclipse Java IDE`, thinking that now I have my `Android SDK` installed it will surely run, the problem here is that when I try to run the executable of the download file it comes back with message:

```
'The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate it's companion shared library'
```

Any help as to what I could do to finally run my `Android SDK` or `Eclipse Java IDE` would much be appreciated.

Comment: o by the way - The Eclipse Java ide was in a zip folder

Comment: Sorry I have now sorted the Eclipse problem: The folders appeared in the Winzip utility and it appeared they were unzipped already - in actual fact they were not, A right click on the Eclipse folder gives you the option to actually unzipp it - which I successfully did.

Comment: There isn't really an executable that *is* the android SDK. There's the sdk manager (an executable called android) and there are a bunch of tools for compiling and working with files and devices.  But you would primarily interact with the SDK through a plugin you add to eclipse (assuming you go the eclipse route)

Comment: O I see, so you are saying the Android sdk does not supply a front end ide to work with but you have to use a plugin ide like Eclipse!, O.K thanks I'm starting to get this now I think

Answer (score 1):

Download eclipse 'Eclipse IDE for Java Developers' from: 
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Then download SDK from: 
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

This video can help you: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLLX9EtG6CI

Answer (score 1):

In fact the SDK has several executables: adb, android, etc. You will access these via Eclipse and/or command line. Setting up the Android development environment is surprisingly painful. It's more or less described [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html). Try that, and when you run into your next roadblock, you let us know.

Comment: I totally agree about 'setting up Android sdk is painful' and I  will sure let you know of any future problems, thanks

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, if you're having troubles getting everything set up, is [MOTODEV Studio](http://developer.motorola.com/tools/motodevstudio/download/) from Motorola.  It's a free product, but requires registration.  One of the use cases we pay attention to is new developers who are having trouble with Eclipse and/or the Android SDK.

Disclaimer: it's my team's product.

Comment: Many thanks - Yes  you know I am a new developer! it must show. I will look at it thanks

Comment: @Mr_leighman - We all were new at one time or another. Good luck.